# Create a loop within a function so that URLs return a dataframe

Tags: function, loops, web-scraping

I was provided with a list of identifiers (in this case the identifier is called an NPI). These identifiers can be copied and pasted to this website (https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/?). I want to return the name of the NPI number, name of the physician, address, phone number, and specialty.

I have over 3,000 identifiers so a copy and paste is not efficient and not easily repeatable for future use.

If possible, I would like to create a list of URLs, pass them into a function, and received a dataframe that provides me with the variables mentioned above (NPI, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, SPECIALTY).

I was able to write a function that produces the URLs needed:

Here are some NPI numbers for reference: 1417024746, 1386790517, 1518101096, 1255500625.

This is my code for reading in the file that contains my NPIs

```
npiList <- c("1417024746", "1386790517", "1518101096", "1255500625")
npiList <- as.list(npiList)
npiList <- unlist(npiList, use.names = FALSE)
```

This is the function to return the list of URLs:

```
npiaddress <- function(x){
url <- paste("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/search-results- 
table?number=",x,"&addressType=ANY", sep = "")
return(url)
}
```

I saved the list to a variable and perhaps this is my downfall:

```
npi_urls <- npiaddress(npiList)
```

From here I wrote a function that can accept a single URL, retrieves the data I want and turns it into a dataframe. My issue is that I cannot pass multiple URLs:

```
npiLookup <- function (x){
url <- x
webpage <- read_html(url)
npi_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td")
npi <- html_text(npi_html)
npi[4] <- gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", npi[4])
npi[4] <- gsub("\r?\t|\r", " ", npi[4])
npiFinal <- npi[c(1:2,4:6)]
npiFinal <- as.data.frame(npiFinal)
npiFinal <- t(npiFinal)
npiFinal <- as.data.frame(npiFinal)
names(npiFinal) <- c("NPI", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "PHONE", "SPECIALTY")
return(npiFinal)
}
```

For example:

If I wanted to get a dataframe for the following identifier (1417024746), I can run this and it works:

```
x <- npiLookup("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/search-results-table?number=1417024746&addressType=ANY")
View(x)
```

My output for the example returns the NPI, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, SPECIALTY as desired, but again, I need to do this for several thousand NPI identifiers. I feel like I need a loop within npiLookup. I've also tried to put npi_urls into the npiLookup function but it does not work.

Thank you for any help and for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way there.  The final step uses this useful R idiom:

`do.call(rbind,lapply(npiList,function(npi) {url=npiaddress(npi); npiLookup(url)}))`

`do.call` is a base R function that applies a function (in this case `rbind`) to the list produced by `lapply`. That list is the result of running your `npiLookup` function on the url produced by your `npiaddress` for each element of `npiList`.

A few further comments for future reference should anyone else come upon this question: (1) I don't know why you're doing the `as.list`, `unlist` sequence at the beginning; it's redundant and probably unnecessary. (2) The NPI registry provides a programming interface (API) that avoids the need to scrape data from the HTML pages; this might be more robust in the long run. (3) The NPI registry provides the entire dataset as a downloadable file; this might have been an easier way to go.